# Illegal argument exception in android : Column _id doesn't exist

Tags: android, exception, sqlite, android-listview, android-cursor

This is the error i'm getting when i try to run my application

Illegal argument exception in android : Column _id doesn't exist

```
   public static final String OBJ_ID="_id";
```

and the creation of database is as follows:

```
 private static final String CREATE_TAB1= "create table " + TABLE_1 + " (" + OBJ_ID + " integer primary key                                     
    autoincrement, " + OBJ_NAME + " text not null, " + DESC1 + " text not null, " + DESC2 + " text not null);";
```

Trying to retrieve the data by using the following function in databasehandler:

```
     public Cursor getAllTable1() {
                return db.query(TABLE_1, 
                                new String[] { OBJ_NAME }, 
                                null, null, null, null, null);
              }
```

This is the function where i communicate with databse

```
    public class List_View extends ListActivity {



public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    super.onCreate(icicle); 
    setContentView(R.layout.displayitems); 

     Databasehelp db = new Databasehelp(this);
    db.open();


    Cursor cursor = db.getAllTable1();

     startManagingCursor(cursor); 

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
           R.layout.list_example_entry, cursor, 
           new String[] {"name"}, 
           new int[] {R.id.name_entry }); 
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Although my database schema consist of column named _id. I changed this to even _ID but didn't seem to work . Can anyone pls help me in resolving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **must** select the column `_id` when binding a Cursor to ListView (Spinner, etc).

So add the `_id` column like this:

```
public Cursor getAllTable1() {
    return db.query(TABLE_1, 
            new String[] { OBJ_ID, OBJ_NAME }, 
            null, null, null, null, null);
}
```